# Http Connection pool shut down when restarting Camel context

Tags: java, apache-camel, spring-camel

I have defined a whole camel context with routes using the component [camel-http4](http://camel.apache.org/http4.html). Basically, upon context startup, this route issues every 5 minuets an http request towards an external server. This works just perfect.

At some point I want to restart the camel context (using JMX), so I just do:

```
if (camelContext.getStatus().isStoppable()) {
  camelContext.stop();
}
```

And later:

```
if (camelContext.getStatus().isStarttable()) {
  camelContext.start();
}
```

Both operations appear to succeed, logs confirm actual stop and start. But when the first http request is issued, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Connection pool shut down

  at org.apache.http.util.Asserts.check(Asserts.java:34)[org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore-nio:4.4.4 org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore-osgi:4.4.4 org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.4]
  at org.apache.http.pool.AbstractConnPool.lease(AbstractConnPool.java:184)[org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore-nio:4.4.4 org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore-osgi:4.4.4 org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.4]
  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.requestConnection(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:251)[commons-codec:commons-codec:1.9 org.apache.httpcomponents:fluent-hc:4.5.2 org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-cache:4.5.2 org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-osgi:4.5.2 org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.2 org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.5.2]
  at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:175)[commons-codec:commons-codec:1.9 org.apache.httpcomponents:fluent-hc:4.5.2 org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-cache:4.5.2 org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-osgi:4.5.2 org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.2 org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.5.2]
```

It looks like the connection pool is in an invalid state.
How can I force the pool re-creation when starting context ?
Is there other way to avoid this error ?

**Versions:**
camel-http4 2.17
apache httpclient 4.5.2

---

I saw already some posts saying the connection manager has to be shared by using  (it's more a workaround) HttpClientConfigurer.
I define and inject my own client configurer, it does not work:

```
public class MyHttpClientConfigurer implements HttpClientConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureHttpClient(HttpClientBuilder httpClientBuilder) {
        httpClientBuilder.setConnectionManagerShared(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the javadoc of those methods on the CamelContext to get details.

Instead of stopping camel context you should use suspend and resume it instead.